# Safari 5.1 breaks CSS table cell spacing

Tags: html, css, safari, drupal-7

My site was working fine across all major browsers right up until the update to Safari 5.1.  Now, the primary navigation is busted up.  I was using `display:table-cell` on the anchor element within the list element and was also using the `font-size:0` hack to remove the spacing in between menu elements.  Has anyone else encountered this issue and have a solution they could offer up?

Before:
[image: Before Image]

After:
[image: After Image]

**CSS:**

```
#navigation {
  padding-top: 7px;
}

#navigation ul.links, /* Main menu and secondary menu links */
#navigation .content ul /* Menu block links */ {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0; /* this is a hack so that the spacing between the menu buttons disappear
                   since they are inline-block elements, this should be unneccessary when
                   CSS3 is approved */
}

#navigation ul.links li, /* A simple method to get navigation links to appear in one line. */
#navigation .content li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;

  /* below is a fix for IE7 to get the main navigation items lined up correctly
   * in one row
   */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
#main-menu ul {
  width: 100%;
}
#main-menu li {
  width: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
#main-menu a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #035B9A;
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="section">
        <h2 class="element-invisible">Main menu</h2>
        <ul id="main-menu" class="links inline clearfix">
            <li class="menu-379 first"><a href="/about-scrubbed">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="menu-401"><a href="/" title="">Research</a></li>
            <li class="menu-385"><a href="/education">Education</a></li>
            <li class="menu-402"><a href="/" title="">Outreach</a></li>
            <li class="menu-403 active-trail active"><a href="/news" title="" class="active-trail active">News &amp; Events</a></li>
            <li class="menu-439"><a href="/people">People</a></li>
            <li class="menu-405"><a href="/" title="">Resources</a></li>
            <li class="menu-406"><a href="/" title="">Publications</a></li>
            <li class="menu-415 last"><a href="/partners">Partners</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Just a note, this is a Drupal 7 site.

Also I freely and humbly admit I am not the very best at CSS markup.  I'm learning a lot right now and am just trying to scrape through.

Comment: Could you post a link to the live site?

Comment: Not a live site, it's developed internally right now with release scheduled for October 1st... really sorry.

Comment: However I did solve my own problem yet again.  I setup the list element to `display: block;` and `float: left;` and it started working again.  I'd post it as an answer but Stack won't let me :(  Need to get that rep up!

Comment: @BoltClock Please check the comment **immediately** above yours.  I have to wait another 6 hours-ish before Stack will let me answer my own question because my rep is not high enough.

Comment: Oh, right, I get it now. Whoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by making the list elements display as block and float them to the left.

```
#navigation ul.links li, /* A simple method to get navigation links to appear in one line. */
#navigation .content li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;

  /* below is a fix for IE7 to get the main navigation items lined up correctly
   * in one row
   */
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For those having trouble with Safari and dimensions for elements set to display:table; I was able to fix my problems by removing the padding and adding padding to a child element set to display:table-cell;

Apparently Safari does not like it when you try to add padding to an element set to display:table; In retrospect, this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times.  This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You want `border-collapse:collapse` on the `display:table` element to remove cell spacing.

Comment: That was my original thought but upon review of my CSS I never actually had a parent element with `display: table;` so I wasn't sure where to put `border-collapse: collapse;`.  However my fix as noted above has everything working again.  I'd post it as an answer but Stack is going to make me wait 7 more hours.

Answer (score 0):

I took your css and html, and added to the css

```
body {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

and I got the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hvy3.png), which looks correct.

This was run under lion, which has Safari 5.1

Comment: Well, that change would definitely have no bearing on layout.  Maybe it's an issue with Safari 5.1 on Windows.  Thanks for checking on it though.