# Safari on iOS6 treats display:table differently

Tags: html, css, safari, ios6

Safari on iOS6 appears to treat display:table differently (compared to Safari on iOS5 and Safari on my PC).

On iOS5, `display:table` forces a div into `box-sizing: border-box mode`, and ignores any attempt to override the box-sizing.

On iOS6, display:table forces a div into `box-sizing: content-box mode`, and also ignored any attempt to override.

The outcome is that `DIV DISPLAY:TABLE WIDTH 250px PADDING-LEFT: 50PX` will be `250px` wide on iOS5 and 300px wide on iOS6.

My question: Is my understanding of this correct? Is there a simple way of getting a div with DISPLAY:TABLE and a left padding to be the same width on iOS5 and iOS6.

FYI the reason I am using DISPLAY:TABLE is because it allows simple vertical centering of my content, which has variable height.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case it helps someone in future, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960083/safari-5-1-breaks-css-table-cell-spacing/11371929#11371929) solved the issue for me.  I moved the padding from the element styled with `display: table;` to the one styled with `display: table-cell;`.

Comment: Seconded, this just fixed the same inconsistency for me between desktop versions of Safari 6.04 and Chrome 26.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and couldn't find any documentation other than this posting. Fortunately for me, it turned out that the container in question didn't need the table: display property.

However, I did test to see if display: table-cell applied the padding the same way as display: table, and it turns out it doesn't. So maybe try applying the display:table property to the parent container (free of padding, of course) and try display: table-cell on the div in question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

This wont have any effect on the iOS5 but will probably fix the display on iOS6 if what you're saying is correct. Sorry no chance to test on iOS6

Comment: Yip. Tried that. box-sizing has no effect if display:table is set.