# Safari adds huge empty space

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am having some problems with Safari.

1. While all browsers display the pages fine, Safari adds a huge white area above the main ContentPlaceholder as shown in the images below. This happens on every page so I guess the problem is in the master page but I can't figure out how to fix it.
2. There is also a small problem with some extra padding above the menu (same happens in Chrome)

I'd appreciate any help. thanks in advance.

[image: All browsers]

[image: Safari]

Here is my master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>
                My ASP.NET Application
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    ................
                </AnonymousTemplate>

                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    ................
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    ................
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftMenu">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftMenuContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>

    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
```

And here is the source code and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/V5aCa/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using `display:table`  safari treats this differently to other browsers

have a look at this question:

[Safari 5.1 breaks CSS table cell spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960083/safari-5-1-breaks-css-table-cell-spacing)

or try using `border-box`:

[CSS does the width include the padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698054/css-does-the-width-include-the-padding)

Your space above the navigation appears because of the skip nav anchor, if you position this absolutely or float it your space should disappear

Comment: Thanks! display:block fixed it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V5aCa/7/ position absolute has got rid of the gap?  I added an id of Test to the link

Comment: Fixed it by using this CSS code: img[alt='Skip Navigation Links'] {
position:absolute;
left:-10000px;
top:auto;
width:1px;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the Margin and Padding of the browser.

```
body {
      margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}
```

that should force safari to start from your set values rather than build up on its default.

Comment: That's already in the CSS. And actually twice! First in the reset and then in defaults.